# Elasticsearch node slower than others

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 nodes, each of them has 5 shards and 2 replicas.
Two of the nodes are way slower than the last one.
On a simple search query "match_all", two nodes answer in 3 secondes, and the third one in 200ms.

They all have been created at the same time, with the same configuration. They contain roughly the same amount of documents.

Do you have any idea what may cause such a difference in response time ?

I'll update my question if you need any missing information

Comment: is there any difference in the machines itself? if so, what is the underlying hardware (cpu, ram, storage, nic, virtual machines or bare metal? if vm, then on the very same vmhost?
how is the java heap set up?

Comment: There are all exactly the same (VM). We killed and re-created one of them, and it works wonders now