# Elasticsearch High query cache eviction

Tags: elasticsearch, caching

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057140/elasticsearch-node-slower-than-others)
I have seen in the statistics of the cluster that the fast node has a value of 0.7 for query cache eviction and the slow one has 24.
I suspect this might be the source of my problem, but I don't know how to fix that. I tried clearing all caches to no avail.